# ajax get json not receive data from django

Tags: ajax, django, jquery

I use django 1.4 run on ubutu.
I'm trying to use jquery/ajax to display data returned from a django method.

my file views.py

```
def json_page(request):

    to_json = {
        "key1" : "value1",
        "key2" : "value2"
    }
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(to_json), mimetype="application/json;charset=UTF-8")
```

my html file:

```
    <script>
        $('document').ready(function() {     
            var url = "http://192.168.1.10:8000/json/";
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                crossDomain: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus) {
                   console.log("error..");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I run file html, fire bug return status = 200 (ok). But not return data,
return case: error

Could you help me fix it. Thanks all,

Comment: Does `alert(data);` alerts any thing?

Comment: return case error: function(xhr, textStatus) { }. But I run http://192.168.1.10:8000/json/ on browser. Browser display 
    {
        "key1" : "value1",
        "key2" : "value2"
    }

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
<script>
            $('document').ready(function() {     
                var url ="http://192.168.1.10:8000/json/";
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "GET",

                    dataType: "json",

                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(success);
                        dat1=data.key1;
                        alert(dat1)
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus) {
                       console.log("error..");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

in your view

```
def json_page(request):

        to_json = {
            "key1" : "value1",
            "key2" : "value2"
        }
        data=json.dumps(to_json)
        return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="application/json)
```